# Statistic with Median

Tags: excel, math, statistics

So I have an excel-sheet where I have different values, for example:

[image]

I want to judge these objects by their values. The values should be between 0 and 1 so in the end I can draw a Matrix. So far so good. What you could do is just take the maximum value and divide the value of the object with that maximum value. For the final result I just take the average of all 3 values.

[image]

Now I have the problem, that if one value is too big, it effects the whole situation. So I know, that the Median tries to resolve this, but how can I use this, to get the percentages/values between 0 and 1? And is there an easy way to do this in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Does excel not have a median function?

Otherwise, you can sort and find the middle value if the number of rows is odd, or the two middle values if the number of rows is even and take the average of those two values to get the median.

Comment: Yes Excel has a Median-Function, but I just need to know what to do with the value. Maybe using quartiles will help, but then again I need to convert the values to values between 0 and 1